# file:/// for url path for local html files?

Tags: html, path

I'm just started web developing not long ago, and I'm wondering why running HTML on my computer comes up with `file:///` and then the file path and name in the browser url bar. For example, what I'm testing right now is:

> file:///D:/WebDesign/HTML/test/default.html

Why isn't it `file://`, or just the pathname?

Is there a certain reason for this?

thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just standard URL code for a local file. A similar syntax is used to refer to a file on a network drive.

However, if you are attempting to develop like that you will run into problems, especially if you intend to test server-side functionality in languages like PHP. You may wish to look into installing a (free) program such as XAMPP or WAMP/MAMP that will emulate an apache server and allow you to test these things.

You can find some very helpful (free) [tutorial videos here](http://phpacademy.org)

Look at the [first three videos here](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11)

And here's another that discusses [installing XAMPP/WAMP](https://phpacademy.org/course/sending-email-from-a-local-server)

Comment: I'm not really developing - it's just for testing. and yes, I do have XAMPP, but i don't really need it right now, i'm using plain html.

Comment: @Jon:- You can check out the link which I have added in my answer. That will help you!!!

Answer (score 4):

`//` is part of the general format of URI schemes.

The next `/` comes after the optional — if defaults to localhost — hostname (since you can have a network path for file URIs).

See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Meaning_of_slash_character) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It is a standard URL code for a local file. Also Check out [this](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fileurl.html):-

> the slash is a general, system-independent way of separating the
>   parts, and in a particular host system it might be used as such in a
>   pathname (as in Unix systems) or internally mapped to another
>   character